# Json format with field name in angular

Tags: angular, service

So I have this service with dummy data, and i wanted to add a field name called 'soeid' to this dummy list but it returns error

Error:

src/app/roaster-load/UploadService/upload.service.ts:10:3 - error TS2322: Type 'Observable<{ soeid: { SOEID: string; }[]; }>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<InvalidSOEIDModel[]>'.
Type '{ soeid: { SOEID: string; }[]; }' is missing the following properties from type 'InvalidSOEIDModel[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.

upload.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { InvalidSOEIDModel } from '../Uploadmodel/uploadmodel';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class UploadService {

 UploadDataReturn(): Observable<InvalidSOEIDModel[]> {
  return of ( {
    "soeid": [
      {
        SOEID: "AAAAA"
      },
      {
        SOEID: "BBBBB"
      }]
  });
 
}
```

uploadmodel.ts:

```
export class InvalidSOEIDModel {

    soeid!: SOEID[]
  }

export class SOEID {
  public SOEID!: string;
}
```

Comment: You're returning an object of Soeid, you need to return array of InvalidSOEIDModel[]

Comment: should i use InvalidSOEIDModel[] in the model ts file? @Train

Comment: no, your return of is returning `{soeid: [{soeied:...}, {soeid:...}]}` instead of `[{soeid: ...}, {soeid:...}]`  or just return a type of InvalidSOEIDModel

Comment: yes, I need to have that array. besides soeid field I also have age field. So I have to keep the field name 'soeids'. So how can I fix so that I can keep the field name 'soeids' in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want it to return an array of InvalidSOEIDModel, this would be the code.

```
UploadDataReturn(): Observable<InvalidSOEIDModel[]> {
  return of ( [{
    "soeid": [
      {
        SOEID: "AAAAA"
      },
      {
        SOEID: "BBBBB"
      }]
  }]);
```

If you just want InvalidSOEIDModel to return, this would be the code.

```
UploadDataReturn(): Observable<InvalidSOEIDModel> {
      return of ( {
        "soeid": [
          {
            SOEID: "AAAAA"
          },
          {
            SOEID: "BBBBB"
          }]
      });
```